# Refactor var without any assignment to const in es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've the following code which I change from

from

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
```

to

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
```

but in addition i've

```
var hostname;
```

which is defined in global scope after all the require modules 
and my question is to what should I change it?
if I put it like const `var hostname;` I think I need to do some initiation but this is something that I didn't do before(I want to change it and keep the behaviour ) so my question is how its recommended to change it?

Comment: You could use `let`.

Comment: @gcampbell - yes but its recommended to use it in this case?

Comment: Either initialize it, or move it to a place where you can initialize it. Avoid mutable globals.

Comment: Do you need `hostname` to be a property of `global` (`var` in top scope creates properties on the global object, but `let` and `const` don't)?

Comment: A "*var without any assigment*", really? In that case you simply should drop it completely.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about using `var` for mutable global variables. No need to refactor it.

Comment: @Bergi Except for when people try to use it to circumvent asynchronous behavior (which is the typical use for them)

Comment: `hostname` sounds like some immutable thing you would import from an external config file...`const host = require('./config.json').hostname;`

Comment: @4castle I meant only the type of variable declaration. Of course there's something wrong with mutable global variable in the first place, yes.